# What happens if I buy a landmark in Assassins Creed: Brotherhood?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

When I buy a landmark, it says "upgrade", but after buying, it still remains broken. :( The income of Rome increases, though. Will the broken buildings/landmarks heal over time?

Does buying a landmark help rebuild the city? I am asking because even if I buy one, it still remains broken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The landmarks will not heal over time, they are just 1000+ year old buildings that cost a lot of florins (The Colosseum is 1425 years old in game at the start). They are simply part of purchasing (rebuilding is the wrong word in this case) all of Rome which gives you a trophy on PS3? (no achievement on 360) and the auditore cape which keeps your wanted level down to 0% all the time. They are also where you find the 6 temples of Romulus and the subject 16 Puzzles.

Comment: The temples of Romulus and the underground really freak me out!! Gone underground twice and don't want to go there again. I rather fight in fresh air :) And what is the subject 16 puzzles anyway?

Comment: @sisir It carries over from AC1 and 2. Subject 16 is also a descendant of Ezio and Altair and goes into the animus before you on the same quest. I believe he gets stuck in animus in a continuous coma (which they warn you about in 1). The goal is to find out what happened to subject 16. I haven't finished this part in brotherhood yet, I'm still working on 100% sync...

Comment: Thanks great info!! I have done couple of 100% sync and most i cant sync 100%. What is the importance of 100% sync? I know that if i do 100% sync i am doing things exactly what Ezio did.

Comment: @Sisir I believe that is correct... I just personally want to 100% sync everything because I enjoy that feeling of doing everything I could have done in a game...

Answer (score 0):

After purchasing the landmark you should see a brief cut scene that shows the landmark being renovated. Purchasing landmarks increases your income and contributes towards a trophy. They can be quiet expensive so perhaps you do not have enough money to buy them.